# How to fetch folder name with path in dynatree?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function

I want to send title of folder on another php page using post method.

Here is my array like this:-

```
 array (size=3)
   0 => 
     array (size=4)
       'title' => string 'mst146' (length=6)
       'isFolder' => boolean true
       'children' => 
          array (size=3)
            0 => 
              array (size=4)
              ...
            1 =>    
              array (size=4)
              ...
            2 => 
          array (size=4)
          ...
       'key' => string 'node2' (length=5)
   1 => 
      array (size=4)
        'title' => string 't124' (length=4)
        'isFolder' => boolean true
        'children' => 
           array (size=0)
           empty
        'key' => string 'node3' (length=5)
   2 => 
     array (size=4)
      'title' => string 'test' (length=4)
      'isFolder' => boolean true
      'children' => 
         array (size=0)
          empty
      'key' => string 'node4' (length=5)
```

Here is my jquery for display dynatree

```
   $("#tree").dynatree({
                checkbox: true,
                sellectMode: 3,
                children: folder,
             });
```

here is my javascript for send selected folder

```
   $("#updateassignfile").click(function () {
                var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
                var tree = $("#tree").dynatree("getTree");
                formData = formData.concat(tree.serializeArray());

                alert("POSTing this:\n" + jQuery.param(formData));
                $.post($('#MAINURL').val() + "admin/ajax/ajax_assignfile.php",
                {"formData":formData, "userid":userid},
                        function () {
                            $('#dynamichomeMessage').html('<div class="alert alert-success">File Assign Setting Successfully Saved.</div>');
                            $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: $("#dynamichomeMessage").offset().top - 120}, 800);
                        }
                );
                return false;
            });
```

This javascript give me array like this

```
  array (size=3)
   0 => 
     array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'selNodes' (length=8)
      'value' => string 'node5' (length=5)
  1 => 
     array (size=2)
       'name' => string 'selNodes' (length=8)
       'value' => string 'node3' (length=5)
  2 => 
     array (size=2)
       'name' => string 'selNodes' (length=8)
       'value' => string 'node4' (length=5)
```

I want to fetch name of folder and path?

i want array like this

```
   0 => 
     array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'foldername' (length=8)
      'value' => string 'path' (length=5)
```

Comment: HI @Kevin : Till Now You Asked 12 Question & Selected Only 3 Answer Out Of Them. Please Reward Them By *Marking Answer As Correct*, If Stack User's Answer Helped You.

Comment: okay dude sorry but can u help me right now? @NanaPartykar